# local scroll Anchor link offset from another Page

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a Page with a FAQ section with anchor Tags who will animate to the specific entry when clicked.

Aditionaly I have a fixed Navi so i did set a Anchor offset in the jquery.

Now I have an anchor link on the Startpage to a specific FAQ entry. The link throws you correctly to the entry, but the offset is of course not appended because local scroll isn't triggered that way.

How is it possible to give these anchors also an offset when you come from another page?

I tried to append: `.wrapperdiv{
   position:relative;
   top:-10px;
}`
to each article. But that doesn't help.

You can see the whole thing here:

[Page](http://rueegg-praxis.ch/site/faq) The anchorlinks links on the indexpage are those on the three icons.

Answer (score 1):

You can test the follwing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Check if there's an anchor in the url
if (window.location.hash){
    var id = window.location.hash.substring(1);
}

// then on window load scroll to the called anchor (that will trigger the window scroll 
// so your upper menu can appear again)
$(window).load(function() {
  if (window.location.hash){
    $.scrollTo('#'+id, 300 // uncomment to set offset if you like, {offset: -70}
  );
 }
});

</script>
```

I'm assuming that you have the function $.scrollTo() defined in your js files, as I've seen it somewhere in http://rueegg-praxis.ch/minimeecache/1349103535a17a59c76f4994e40f602abc25dd4d8b.js